# How to find out what process is starting a DLL after logging in

Tags: windows-7, boot, dll

I have a user on a Windows 7 32bit machine. When this user logs in, they get the following error message:

> "There was a problem starting
>   C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\eleluqizevaxikuf.dll
>   - The specified module could not be found."

How can I determine what process or program is looking for this DLL? A Google search doesn't turn up any results for the specified DLL name.

Comment: Have you tried searching the registry for said DLL's filename?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) to find out which applications are starting during Windows start up. You can probably run each of these to find the offending program.

Answer (score 1):

With a dll name like that it's time to run a full virus scan.

Comment: I think the fact that _"There was a problem starting"_ it means the file is already gone. The problem here is that something still references it. A full virus scan couldn't hurt though.

Comment: Yes, a full scan found nothing